# Conditional based on whether Codeception test passes or not

Tags: codeception

I want to run a PHP program where the program flow control is a conditional based on whether a Codeception test passes or not. So that:

```
<?php
if ( some cept or cest passes){do something...}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry Jim but this is probably too broad a question for SO Q&A format.  The help guide [recommends you avoid "what is the best"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) style questions.

Comment: [Stack Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be able to help.

Comment: Destination, this is not a broad question at all. I fixed the phrasing.

Comment: I am quite confident that it is impossible to do that.  @depends only works in the scope of one file.

Comment: I mean that there is no built-in way. You could store result of the first test in the global variable, class property or in a file. It's up to you.